# Can't seem to get it to find the element by label - Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find the element by label but it doesn't seem to work. Please let me know what is wrong.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@label='First Name']")).sendKeys("MY NAME");

Here's the code:

```
<div
        data-ng-class="{ 'has-feedback has-success' : rules[0].test(user) && rules[1].test(user) && !usernameUnavailable}"
        class="form-group required">
    <label
            for="username"
            class="control-label">
        Username
    </label>
    <div data-ng-show="usernameUnavailable">
        Username unavailable
    </div>
    <input  autocomplete="off"
            data-ng-enter="usernameChange($event, change, next)"
            name="username"
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            data-ng-model="user.username"
            data-ng-trim="true"/>
```

Comment: @alecxe I'm new to this, I'm not sure how to accept an answer. I've tried to give it a thumbs up but apparently I need a 15 reputation before I vote. The answer did help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `//div[@label='First Name']`

This does not make much sense - it means get me the `div` element that has an *attribute* `label` equal to `First Name`. But you have a `label` *element* instead:

```
//div[label = 'First Name']
```

Or, if you are actually targeting the `input`, check it's `name` attribute:

```
//input[@name = 'username']
```

If you still want to use `label`, use [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//label[@for = 'username']/following-sibling::input
```